# Переключение между тегами

Tags: visual-studio-code

Как можно быстро переключаться между тегами в VS Code? Пример: через emmet я создаю список `<ol>`, с помощью клавиши TAB можно переключаться к следущему тегу `<li>` и так до конца списка, но когда меняешь фокус на что то другое и потом возращаешься, то так уже нельзя делать. Как сделать что бы снова можно было переключаться по тегам?
Мне нужно чтобы курсор переключился во внутрь тега.
[image: example]

Comment: Может Ctrl + space ?

Comment: Мне нужно что когда я написал текст в теге li нажать клавишу и оно переключилось следущему тегу li. Так можно сделать сначала с помощю TAB, но потом уже нет.

Comment: Это называется "сниппет". К редактированию сниппетов после их завершения возвращаться нельзя. Эта фича задумана как простой пользовательский шаблон, не более того.

Comment: А вообще, имхо, Emmet - прошлый век. Используйте нормальный препроцессор, если вам так нужен синтаксический сахар в HTML. [Pug](https://pugjs.org) например.

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf, но ведь emmet это не синтаксический сахар

Comment: @Grundy ну а что это? Назначение у него то же самое.

Comment: Да суть не в emmet, мне просто нужно что бы, я не мышкой перетаскивал курсор или спомощю клавиш со стрелками. А просто нажал клавишу и что бы курсор оказался на новой строке между тегами как на картинке.

Comment: Ознакомьтесь с тем, что такое сниппеты; создайте свой собственный и поймёте как это работает. Здесь всё детально расписано: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets